# Redshift indirect permissions

Tags: permissions, amazon-redshift

I am trying to give redshift read-only permission to a group of people in our organization.

We have different schemas but I am only granting USAGE and SELECT permission to PUBLIC schema for people outside of our team.

The problem is, I have views in PUBLIC schema that access tables/views in other schemas, and at the moment, they wouldn't run as users don't have permission to those other schemas.

I was wondering, is there a way to give people indirect access to different schemas without giving them permission to query those other schemas directly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the answer (well, seems like its working for me) :

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO GROUP public_users_group;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO GROUP public_users_group;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_for_indirect_access TO GROUP public_users_group;
```

It seems like anytime a new entity is created in any of above-mentioned schemas, the permissions' script needs to be executed again so every half our I run above script in a cron job using python.